# React native: zIndex not taken seriously on Android

Tags: react-native

There is a container component which holds an Image. This container is supposed to be **behind** text in a different container component. Both container components are at the same depth from Root element. Explaining the exact structure is a bit complicated.

The gist of the issue is that zIndex is respected on iOS, but not on Android. You can clone the Expo project here

https://github.com/fullhdpixel/stopwatch_RN

iOS screenshot (correct):

[image: iOS screenshot]

Android screenshot (incorrect, see laps text)

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The issue has been solved. The solution was straightforward, it was just a rearrangement of elements.

See this commit: https://github.com/fullhdpixel/stopwatch_RN/commit/ec6cb79945fabbf0b718cbdb98f201d92f749a73

Answer (score 16):

On Android `zIndex` fights with `elevation` property. If you are using `elevation` purely for the shadow, you should use a component like this to get the shadow - https://github.com/Kishanjvaghela/react-native-cardview

Or you can try setting `elevation` but with `backgroundColor: 'transparent'`. I think this will raise the element but not give it shadow. (if you try this way let me know how if it still works, I forget, it might have been a bug that they fixed).

Edit:

Just tried out that elevation without shadow trick, it works, here is a snack to try with expo - https://snack.expo.io/@noitsnack/elevation-without-shadow-trick

Comment: I dont understand. Im just using elevation for buttons, but not the part where the issue is. The Text Container is below the Image container.

Comment: @Fullhdpixel if you can create a snack with your problem i can fix it for you easily. I tried downloading and runing your repo but it wouldn't work.

Answer (score 0):

apply elevation: 0 for component that covers component that you want to be on top (if shadow is not needed)